# Does fame cause any specific problems for Harry Potter in the first book?

Tags: harry-potter

Harry became famous for something he did as a baby.

**On what specific occasions does Harry's fame cause him, his family, his teachers and peers trouble?**

Comment: And when is your paper due? Were you supposed to have done it over xmas? ;-)

Comment: it is due tomorrow :\

Comment: Voted to reopen - Valorum's answer is quite concise and canon-based.

Answer (score 10):

### Harry

**Harry's fame is the direct cause of Dumbledore leaving Harry with the Dursleys, a decision that results in his suffering a decade of abuse.**

> ‘Exactly,’ said Dumbledore, looking very seriously over the top of his
>   half-moon glasses. ‘It would be enough to turn any boy’s head. Famous
>   before he can walk and talk! Famous for something he won’t even
>   remember! Can’t you see how much better off he’ll be, growing up away
>   from all that until he’s ready to take it?’

**Harry's fame results in the Dursleys not telling Harry anything about his parentage.**

> ‘But yeh must know about yer mum and dad,’ he said. ‘I mean, they’re famous. You’re famous.’
>   ‘What? My – my mum and dad weren’t famous, were they?’
>   ‘Yeh don’ know … yeh don’ know …’ Hagrid ran his fingers through his hair, fixing Harry with a bewildered stare.
>   ‘Yeh don’ know what yeh are?’ he said finally.
>   Uncle Vernon suddenly found his voice.
>   ‘Stop!’ he commanded. ‘Stop right there, sir! I forbid you to tell the boy anything!’

**It results in his feeling disconnected from his fellow wizards.**

> ‘Everyone thinks I’m special,’ he said at last. ‘All those people in
>   the Leaky Cauldron, Professor Quirrell, Mr Ollivander … but I don’t
>   know anything about magic at all. How can they expect great things?
>   I’m famous and I can’t even remember what I’m famous for. I don’t know
>   what happened when Vol– sorry – I mean, the night my parents died.’

**Harry spends much of his early months at Hogwarts suffering from an unwarranted [halo effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halo_effect), until he actually manages to achieve something of note.**

> Harry left the changing room alone some time later, to take his Nimbus
>   Two Thousand back to the broomshed. He couldn’t ever remember feeling
>   happier. He’d really done something to be proud of now – no one could
>   say he was just a famous name any more.

**Snape openly mocks his fame**

> ‘Ah, yes,’ he said softly, ‘Harry Potter. Our new – celebrity.’
>   Draco Malfoy and his friends Crabbe and Goyle sniggered behind their hands.   Snape finished calling the names and looked up at the class. His eyes were black like Hagrid’s, but they had none of Hagrid’s warmth. They were cold and empty and made you think of dark tunnels.
>
> ...
>
> ‘I don’t know, sir,’ said Harry.
>   Snape’s lips curled into a sneer.
>   ‘Tut, tut – fame clearly isn’t everything.’
>   He ignored Hermione’s hand.

**Fame is a fickle mistress. Harry goes from uber-popular to uber-unpopular in a heartbeat when he does something dumb.**

> At first, Gryffindors passing the giant hour-glasses that recorded the
>   house points next day thought there’d been a mistake. How could they
>   suddenly have a hundred and fifty points fewer than yesterday? And
>   then the story started to spread: Harry Potter, the famous Harry
>   Potter, their hero of two Quidditch matches, had lost them all those
>   points, him and a couple of other stupid first-years.
>
> From being one of the most popular and admired people at the school,
>   Harry was suddenly the most hated. Even Ravenclaws and Hufflepuffs
>   turned on him, because everyone had been longing to see Slytherin lose
>   the House Cup. Everywhere Harry went, people pointed and didn’t
>   trouble to lower their voices as they insulted him. Slytherins, on the
>   other hand, clapped as he walked past them, whistling and cheering,
>   ‘Thanks Potter, we owe you one!’

**Harry's fame and popularity serves to highlight and deepen the discontinuity between his time at Hogwarts and his time at home with the Dursleys.**

> ‘See you, Potter!’
>   ‘Still famous,’ said Ron, grinning at him.
>   ‘Not where I’m going, I promise you,’ said Harry.

Comment: People can only suffer from impostor syndrome if they have indeed achieved something on their own - but Harry didn't. I see what you mean, but impostor syndrome isn't the right name for it, AFAIK.

Comment: @Gallifreian - You're not wrong. It's a sort of [Dunning-Kruger effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dunning%E2%80%93Kruger_effect) where people think he's special when in fact he's relatively mundane.

Comment: It's not an impostor *syndrome*, he's simply an impostor - all he did to become famous was 1) nothing and 2) nothing. On the other hand, I'd argue he does suffer from this syndrome in years 4 and 5, when he thinks he shouldn't have survived the Triwizard Tournament, when in fact he did very well - *moral fibre*, facing Voldemort at the graveyard, etc.

Comment: @Gallifreian - Related Q on another stack [Is there a term that means the opposite of the Impostor Syndrome?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/82476/is-there-a-term-that-means-the-opposite-of-the-impostor-syndrome).

Comment: A comment on another question you linked: `outpostor syndrome` :D

Comment: @Gallifreian - Yes. LOL.

Comment: I like the chutzpah of asking that there.

Comment: @SQB  -  they have no idea they're being tricked into helping Valorum make a better answer :D *evil laugh*

Comment: @Gallifreian - I find it interesting how my questions are received here (respected, admired) compared to how they're received on other sites (VTC frenzy, punk the noob)

Comment: Must be the [halo effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halo_effect).

Comment: @Gallifreian - Well indeed. I can only hope that we treat new users better. I suspect we don't